# How can I make the transparent part of an image not show up

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, I am animating two images one small on top of the larger one. The small is generated using Photoshop and the visible part is surrounded by a checkerboard pattern (which is supposed to be transparent). When the animation runs, the images appear but the checkerboard patters shows up as a grey square.

How can I make it transparent.

This is how the imagebutton is setup in the layout.xml

```
    <ImageButton        
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="184dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/videothumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/button_power_on" />
```

And the animation file:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <alpha
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromAlpha="0.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.8"
      android:duration="5000"
      android:repeatMode="reverse"
      android:repeatCount="infinite"
       />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are using an ImageButton and the grey color you see is the default background of the button. Use an ImageView instead.

Comment: I have to use an ImageButton because I would like the user to click on  it to select the next step. I made the button background transparent with android:background="@android:color/transparent" and the grey disappeared. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about that, I never use ImageButton... All Views are clickable, you can add click listeners even to TextView, and also background drawables, which show pressed / selected / etc. state.